# How to enable action with Lottie Button animation in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, animation, swiftui, lottie

I have a simple project which is running a Lottie animation when tapping on a Button.

```
struct ContentView: View {

@State var number = 0
@State var toogleValue : Bool = false

var body: some View {
    ZStack {
        Color.green.opacity(0.2)
        ZStack {
            LottieButton(filename: "17247-happy-flower")
               .frame(width: 200)
               .onTapGesture {
                    self.number += 1
            }
            Text("number = \(self.number)")
            .offset( y: 150)
        }
    }.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
}
}
```

What I am trying to achieve is:  Whenever the user taps on the Button, the animation should start and the number counter should increase by 1.

What is happening now: The counter is increasing by 1 but the animation is not playing.

What I tried: When I comment // onTapGesture {self.number += 1} the animation is working fine, but then the counter is not working.

Here is the Lottie Button:

```
  struct LottieButton: UIViewRepresentable {
/// Create a button.
let animationButton = AnimatedButton()
var filename = "LottieLogo2"

func makeUIView(context: UIViewRepresentableContext<LottieButton>) -> UIView {
let view = UIView()

let animation = Animation.named(filename)
animationButton.animation = animation
animationButton.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit

animationButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
view.addSubview(animationButton)

animationButton.clipsToBounds = false
   /// Set animation play ranges for touch states
animationButton.setPlayRange(fromMarker: "touchDownStart", toMarker: "touchDownEnd", event: .touchUpInside)
 //  animationButton.setPlayRange(fromMarker: "touchDownEnd", toMarker: "touchUpCancel", event: .touchUpOutside)
 //  animationButton.setPlayRange(fromMarker: "touchDownEnd", toMarker: "touchUpEnd", event: .touchUpInside)
                                 
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
    animationButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor),
    animationButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor),
])

return view
}

func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIView, context: UIViewRepresentableContext<LottieButton>) {
         
}
}
```

I assume the problem is due to the hierarchy of the View, but I am not sure.

[image: Screenshot from the app]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to embrace the `Coordinator` that you can use with a `UIViewRepresentable`.

By having a `Coordinator` class it allows you to add a target to the `animationView`. Targets and Objective-C exposed functions can only be added to classes. This means that you can perform any action when you tap on the animation.

To our `LottieButton` struct we pass two parameters a `filename` and an `action`. The action is basically a closure allowing us to pass a piece of code that will be executed later.

We set up the `Coordinator` by passing a reference to the `LottieButton` that we are creating, then we add the target. This needs to be added after the call to `super.init` as we need to user `self`.

```
import SwiftUI
import Lottie

struct LottieButton: UIViewRepresentable {

    typealias UIViewType = UIView
    let animationView = AnimatedButton()
    let filename: String
    let action: () -> Void

    func makeUIView(context: UIViewRepresentableContext<LottieButton>) -> UIView {
        let view = UIView()

        let animation = Animation.named(filename)
        animationView.animation = animation
        animationView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit

        animationView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(animationView)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            animationView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor),
            animationView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor),
        ])

        return view
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIView, context: UIViewRepresentableContext<LottieButton>) {

    }

    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }


    class Coordinator: NSObject {
        let parent: LottieButton

        init(_ parent: LottieButton) {
            self.parent = parent
            super.init()
            parent.animationView.addTarget(self, action: #selector(touchUpInside), for: .touchUpInside)
        }

        // this function can be called anything, but it is best to make the names clear
        @objc func touchUpInside() {
            parent.action()
        }
    }
}
```

This then means that we can do the following in our ContentView. Our action parameter can now perform whatever we want when we tap button.

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @State private var tapped: Int = 0

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            LottieButton(filename: "loading", action: {
                print("tapped")
                tapped += 1
            })
            .frame(width: 200, height: 200)

            Text("tapped count \(tapped)")
        }
    }
}
```

Here it is working:

[image: Image showing animated button working]

Comment: Do you by chance have any example tutorial on how to play the animation while fetching the data and stop when the data is loaded on the screen? I am still struggling with that issue.